# Why does jQuery only return integer height if setting a double value clearly renders differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, pixel

I've got an image that is 924px in height. The image has been created to look appropriate at this height. Stretching it is not desireable.

Ontop of this image, I need to overlay a variable number of same-height div elements. In this particular instance I need to overlay 88. As such, the math is pretty clear:

> 924 / 88 = 10.5

Each div element must be 10.5 pixels in height to properly overlay my image.

Visually, everything looks great! I have 88 elements and they're all 10.5 pixels in height. If I set their height to 11px or 10px I see visual differences.

However, using jQuery:

```
$('div').height();  // 10
$('div').css('height'); //10px
```

?? Huh? They're clearly 10.5 pixels in height, not 10. If I dig into the element's style property -- I see 10.5 pixels.

What's going on? Can I get jQuery to play nice with double values for height/width? Why is it so opposed?

Comment: Browsers round pixels, there's no such thing as half a pixel.

Comment: How do you expect a half pixel to be displayed on your screen ?

Comment: @elclanrs well that's not 100% clear, esp. on "retina" displays, but nevertheless I agree that it's probably the browser doing the rounding and not jQuery.

Comment: This is not something you can do with jQuery or JavaScript, and a pixel is either this color or that color, can't both...

Comment: What does it say the height of the elements are when you inspect the element using a browser tool? Just curious, because it shouldn't be 10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jquery.height()` actually converts it to the actual amount of pixels it is taking up on the screen.

You may find, if you iterated through every div on your page a mixture of height 10's and 11's, since you can't render something on only half a pixel, to actually render things that take half a pixel you would need to decide whether it will take a pixel or not.  The browser will alternate between which divs do and don't to try and get the best possible result.

Comment: Yeah fair enough it's probably just rounding between 10 and 11.